# Problem displaying server data on angular with async pipe (empty page) no error displays

Tags: angular, angular8

Being new to Angular\TS, I want to use Async Pipe to display JSON data . Following is the code with Model Interface.It compiles but doesn't display anything(empty page) and no error displays. what can i do? any help can be useful

Following my:

*service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { OurProducts } from "../models/our-products.models";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, map } from "rxjs";
import { ArticlesSingle } from "../single-product/models/articles-single.models";
import { APIService } from "../api.service";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OurProductsServices {

 
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private apiService:APIService){
      this.getProductList();
    }

    myProduct$!: Observable<ArticlesSingle[]>

    myProduct!: ArticlesSingle[] 

      toServer(myProduct: ArticlesSingle[]): OurProducts[] {
       return myProduct.map(myProduct=> ({
          id: myProduct.id,
          title: myProduct.title,
          image_url: myProduct.image_url,
          description: myProduct.description,
          price: myProduct.price,
          add_like: myProduct.add_like,
          created_date: myProduct.created_date,
          in_stock: myProduct.in_stock
        }))
      }

      getProductList(){
        this.apiService.getProductList().subscribe(
          (res)=>{

          }
        )
      }

      getAllProducts():Observable<ArticlesSingle[]> {
         return this.http.get<ArticlesSingle[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/articles').pipe(
          map(result=> Array.from(result))
         )
      };


}

*
```

Component.ts*

```
export class OurProductsListsComponent implements OnInit {

  myProduct$!: Observable<OurProducts[]>;
  myProduct!: OurProducts [];

  constructor(private ourProductsService: OurProductsServices) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myProduct$ = this.ourProductsService.getAllProducts(); 
  }

}
```

*component.html*

```
   <app-our-products *ngFor="let myProduct of myProduct$ | async" [ourProduct]="myProduct"></app-our-products>
```

Any help will be welcome

Comment: do you see the HTTP call in the network tab ? Do you see your `app-our-products` components in your browser's elements tab ?

Comment: it seems like you declared twice `myProduct` (once in TS, and once in HTML). Can your remove the TS declaration ? Variables may be shadowed...

Answer (score 0):

Try next one:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.ourProductsService.getAllProducts()
     .subscribe(res => this.myProduct$.next(res); 
}
```

Comment: When i try this, it says "Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<ArticlesSingle[]>'.ts(2339)" and "next" is underlined in red as error.

Comment: for "random" I don't see my app-our-products components in your browser's elements tab. Even if i add element throught string interpolation {{}}, it doesn't appear in my browser's element tab. i gonna be crazy

Comment: Change type of myProduct$ to BehaviourSubject..

Comment: Hi everybody, i always try to solve my problems but now i can see this problem: "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform". How a can I solve it? Please help me!!!

Comment: Hi everyone, I finally found the source of my problem. It was at the pagination level of my API. I had not put my model in adequacy with that of the pagination. Thank you all